# Urlmapping for camel case with more than one meaningful step

Tags: grails

As we know, grails automatically maps `MyController` to `[root]/my` as expected, but if I have `MyAnotherController` it gets mapped to `[root]/myAnother`. I would like to get it mapped automatically to `[root]/my/another`.

Is there a way to do this without putting additional URL mapping directives to `conf/UrlMappings.groovy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open JIRA related to this (placing controllers in sub folders/ packages). Go ahead and vote for it. I would love to see this implemented in Grails.

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-1243